# how to copy files from aws s3 to hadoop hdfs

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I copy files from aws s3 to hadoop with command"

> **hadoop distcp s3://xxx@aaa/ hdfs://s3/alc**"

but it does not work.

And I find it transports to **s3-1-w.amazonaws.com**.

Then I edit file "/etc/hadoop/conf/jets3t.properties" and add "**s3service.s3-endpoint=cn-north-1.amazonaws.com.cn**.
now I get the exception:

> "**Copy failed: java.net.UnknownHostException: alc.cn-north-1.amazonaws.com.cn**"

how can I fix it?